# How to find unique set values in the list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries with same set of keys.
I need to find either a single key with unique values across all dictionaries or a set of keys with unique combination of values.

Example:

```
# Case 1.
tags1 = [{'a': 10, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, 
         {'a': 11, 'b': 2, 'c': 4},
         {'a': 12, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]

# Case 2.
tags2 = [{'a': 10, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, 
         {'a': 10, 'b': 2, 'c': 4},
         {'a': 12, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]

# If there is a key with unique values for each key in the list of dicts 
# than it's simple e.g. a: 10, a: 11, a: 12 in Case 1
# But in Case 2 where there is no a single key with such properties,
# than there is a problem
def unique_tag(tags):
    metric_tags = list(tags[0].keys())
    for tag in metric_tags:
        values = set([i[tag] for i in tags if tag in i])
        if len(values) == len(tags):
            return [tag]

# ==== What we have: ====
# Case 1. - works
unique_set_of_tags = unique_tags(tags1)
print(unique_set_of_tags)
>>> ['a']

# Case 2. - doesn't work
unique_set_of_tags = unique_tags(tags2)
print(unique_set_of_tags)
>>> []

# ==== What we want: =====
# Case 2.
unique_set_of_tags = unique_tags(tags2)
print(unique_set_of_tags)
>>> ['a', 'c']
# because combination of values for this tags are unique
# [(10, 3), (10, 4), (12, 3)]
```

Comment: Show us your effort in code, please.

Comment: What is the logic in deciding what  `unique_tags`  are. `c` is the sam in both dicts, but only in `unique_tags` in the second case.

Comment: @MarkMeyer In Case 2, `a` alone isn't enough to distinguish all dicts (because of the duplicate `10`), but the combination of `a` and `c` is.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem in your code is that you are not combining multiple elements to check for nested combinations (You are only checking if a list has only unique values but you also need to check if lists of lists are unique).

I would rather make a matrix and then check for all possible combinations of a given axis (it looks strange to use lists of dictionaries if you have duplicated keys and you wont use them to access any value). So, for example, we could generate a matrix with numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.array([[v for v in d.values()] for d in tags1])
[[10  2  3]
 [11  2  4]
 [12  2  3]]
```

now we need to check if, given one or more columns, the sequence of all horizontal slices (rows) are unique. We could use the itertools module to generate the combinations of columns we want to check:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

def unique_set_of_tags(tags):
    matrix = np.array([[v for v in d.values()] for d in tags])
    m = matrix.shape[0]
    n = matrix.shape[1]
    for n_elem in range(n):
        for c in itertools.combinations([i for i in range(m)], r=n_elem+1):
            if np.unique(matrix[:, c], axis=0).shape[0] == m:
                return [k for i, k in enumerate(list(tags[0].keys())) if i in c]
    return []
```

after we have the columns that corresponds to the unique combination we transform back from a vertical axis index to your dictionary's keys.